# Selenium c# - Clearing cache and browsing data

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

In my test script, I am having selenium open up the chrome settings page. On that page, I want it to select the "Clear Data" button.

```
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm"));
```

I get an error saying the element not found. I have tried using just with the "ID" as well. Is there another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button is really hard to reach, because polymer.
Try this one, it works for me.

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Selenium_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static IWebDriver driver;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");

            IWebElement root1 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-ui"));
            IWebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
            IWebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-main"));
            IWebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);
            IWebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-basic-page"));
            IWebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);
            IWebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-section > settings-privacy-page"));
            IWebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
            IWebElement root5 = shadowRoot4.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog"));
            IWebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(root5);
            IWebElement root6 = shadowRoot5.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataDialog"));
            IWebElement root7 = root6.FindElement(By.CssSelector("cr-tabs[role='tablist']"));

            root7.Click();

            IWebElement clearDataButton = root6.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm"));

            clearDataButton.Click();
        }

        private static IWebElement expandRootElement(IWebElement element)
        {
            return (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a c# version of @Lanki but also makes sure to click the 'Basic' tab, 'All time' time range and clicks Browsing, Cookies and Cache checkboxes if not already checked. Thanks @Lanki !

```
    private static IWebElement expandRootElement(IWebElement element) {
        return (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
    }

    private static void clickSettingsCheckbox(IWebElement chkBox) {
        string check = chkBox.GetAttribute("checked");
        if (check == null) chkBox.Click();
    }

    public static void clearCacheAndCookies() {

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
        driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();

        IWebElement root1 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-ui"));
        IWebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
        IWebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-main"));
        IWebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);
        IWebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-basic-page"));
        IWebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);
        IWebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-section > settings-privacy-page"));
        IWebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
        IWebElement root5 = shadowRoot4.FindElement(By.CssSelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog"));
        IWebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(root5);
        IWebElement root6 = shadowRoot5.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataDialog"));

        IWebElement root7 = root6.FindElement(By.CssSelector("cr-tabs[role='tablist']"));
        IWebElement shadowRoot7 = expandRootElement(root7);
        IWebElement root8 = shadowRoot7.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='tab selected']"));
        IWebElement root9 = shadowRoot7.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='tab']"));

        if (!root8.Text.Equals("Basic")) root9.Click();   // Select Basic tab if not selected
        
        IWebElement rootDropDown = root6.FindElement(By.Id("clearFromBasic"));
        IWebElement shadowDropDown = expandRootElement(rootDropDown);
        IWebElement timeRange = shadowDropDown.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownMenu"));
        var selectElement = new SelectElement(timeRange);
        selectElement.SelectByText("All time");

        clickSettingsCheckbox(root6.FindElement(By.Id("browsingCheckboxBasic")));
        clickSettingsCheckbox(root6.FindElement(By.Id("cookiesCheckboxBasic")));
        clickSettingsCheckbox(root6.FindElement(By.Id("cacheCheckboxBasic")));

        IWebElement clearDataButton = root6.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm"));

        clearDataButton.Click();

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(wd => wd.Url.StartsWith("chrome://settings"));
        Thread.Sleep(300);

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm a newbie I couldn't upvote to @Lanki answer.
It worked like a charm.

Here's a JAVA version of the same script:

```java
WebElement root1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("settings-ui"));
WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.cssSelector("settings-main"));
WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);
WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.cssSelector("settings-basic-page"));
WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);
WebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(By.cssSelector("settings-section > settings-privacy-page"));
WebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
WebElement root5 = shadowRoot4.findElement(By.cssSelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog"));
WebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(root5);
WebElement root6 = shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataDialog"));
WebElement root7 = root6.findElement(By.cssSelector("cr-tabs[role='tablist']"));

root7.click();

WebElement clearDataButton = root6.findElement(By.cssSelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm"));

clearDataButton.click();
```